# Postgresql regex to return multiple values

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql

I have a scenario in postgres where I need to gather all entries between multiple sets of square brackets.

The following example would be what I would expect to capture this:

```
SELECT (regexp_matches('Hello [World] How [Are] You','\[(.*?)\]'))
```

But this simply returns

```
{World}
```

ignoring the second [Are] section.

In a regular regex this seems to work, so I'm unsure as to why its failing here.

Ideally, I would like to return the result as as csv text string. 
e.g.

```
World,Are
```

but I can't seem to find the right query to do this.

Any input appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use the 'g' flag

```
SELECT (regexp_matches('Hello [World] How [Are] You','\[(.*?)\]','g'))
```

> The "g" flag indicates that the regular expression should be tested
>   against all possible matches in a string.